# CI tool with code metrics for ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I need to integrate a **CI**(continues integration)+**CD**(continuous deployment) tool for my ruby on rails application.
It would be great if it has the following features.

- **Code metric tool** like (metric_fu)
- **Gitlab,Gitlub** for repository managements.

Following are the list of CI tool I'm consider.

```
 https://travis-ci.org/ 
 https://circleci.com/ 
 https://www.shippable.com/
 https://www.codeship.io/ 
 https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org
 http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/ 
 https://drone.io/
```

​please help me to compare the feature of these CI tools......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(full disclosure, I work for ThoughtWorks)

I'd replace CruiseControl.rb with http://www.go.cd/ or http://snap-ci.com - ThoughtWorks isn't actively updating CruiseControl.rb since Go CD came out several years ago. Both of the newer tools (also from TW) are designed with CD at their core.

To the main part of your question - With any of the tools you mentioned I'd recommend calling the code metrics tool of your choice as one of the stages, and not relying on the CI/CD tool to have that knowledge natively. Generally speaking, CI/CD servers are used to orchestrate a process that relies on several other tools like build systems, metrics tools, testing tools etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found **magnum-ci.com** recently and feel it suites my entire need.

Hope this may help ROR enthusiastic...

Answer (score 0):

[Magnum CI](http://magnum-ci.com) should be great for what you need.

It also deploys to Heroku, which hosts Rails apps. So if you want it to run some tests then deploy automatically, it sounds like it could be a good fit!